# Angular > getter vs method in template

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component

To avoid writing logic in the *ngIf of the template for example.

`<div *ngIf="a === 3 && b === 'foo'"></div>`

I usually create ad hoc method for e.g.

```
public isOk(): boolean {
  return a === 3 && b === 'foo'
}
```

and the previous code become:

`<div *ngIf="isOk()"></div>`

Is this a good practice?

is it right to use a method or is it better to use a getter?

Why should we use one or another?

pro? cons?

so, with a getter, it would become:

```
public get isOk(): boolean {
  return a === 3 && b === 'foo'
}
```

and the previous code become:

`<div *ngIf="isOk"></div>`

Comment: @tmsbrndz, and a getter too :) . To check simply add a console.log("hi") in the getter or in the method

Answer (score 0):

The  better way is to create additional property in your component class.

Component class:

```
...
// if a & b changed, as instance you are subscribed 
// to Observable in your ngOnInit
isOk: boolean; 

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.httpService.getSomeData()
    .subscribe(data => this.isOk = data.a === 3 && data.b === 'foo');
  // don't forget to unsubscribe
}
...
```

In component template:

```
<div *ngIf="isOk"></div>
```

In another way your getter or method will be fired every time, when angular change detection is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

For the most optimal performance, you should combine rxjs and the `| async` pipe.

For example now you have the [following application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ba3jme?file=src/main.ts):

```
@Component({
  ...,
  template: `
    <h1 *ngIf="isOk()">Hello world!</h1>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="b">`,
})
export class App implements DoCheck {
  a = 0;
  b = '';

  isOk() {
    console.log('ran function');
    return (this.a === 3) && (this.b === 'foo');
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('DoCheck');
  }
}
```

Which results in the following:

[image: Function binding runs several times]

Notice that the function is run several times on each change. The function is even run twice when we're simply **focusing one of the textboxes**.

If we're using Observables instead, we get [the following](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpvdyu?file=src%2Fmain.ts):

```
@Component({
  ...,
  template: `
    <h1 *ngIf="isOk$ | async">Hello world!</h1>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="a$ | async" (ngModelChange)="a$.next($event)">
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="b$ | async" (ngModelChange)="b$.next($event)">
  `,
})
export class App implements DoCheck {
  a$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  b$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  isOk$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.isOk$ = combineLatest([this.a$, this.b$])
      .pipe(map(([a, b]) => {
        console.log('ran function');
        return (a === 3) && (b === 'foo');
      }));
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('DoCheck');
  }
}
```

The result of this is:

[image: Observable function is only run when necessary]

Note that the rxjs `map` function is only run when one of the inputs changes, no more than necessary.

Additionally we can now modify the ChangeDetection strategy to `OnPush`:

- OnPush with the [first demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o7gewb?file=src%2Fmain.ts): Miraculously this still seems to work as expected
- OnPush with the [second demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-854gjh?file=src%2Fmain.ts): This is now perfectly possible and should not result in any problems